# Sql query request taking long time with inner join a special select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am supposed to execute a simple query which use only one table.

The execute result is not false - but it takes such long time.

```
SELECT SUM(montantCommande) as total 
    FROM export_commandes 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM export_adherent) AS table_adherent
    WHERE export_commandes.client_id=table_adherent.ID
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve through this query. Explain.

Comment: I am creating a customer profiling tree and i would like to develop the query by using condition, that's why i put INNER JOIN (select... ) because after i would like to insert condition like for example INNER JOIN (select ... WHERE ... AND ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(montantCommande) as total 
FROM export_commandes c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ID FROM export_adherent) a
     ON c.client_id = a.ID;
```

When you use a subquery in MySQL (but not in most other databases), it goes through the effort of actually creating a derived table.  This not only adds extra overhead, but it also interferes with indexes for optimization.

Instead, phrase the query as:

```
SELECT SUM(montantCommande) as total 
FROM export_commandes c INNER JOIN
     export_adherent a
     ON c.client_id = a.ID;
```

Then, you want indexes on `export_commands(client_id)` and `export_adherent(id)` (only one will be used but it is unclear).  You can add `montantCommande` as a second key in the appropriate index as a further optimization.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine. And now, if i would like to insert a condition in my INNER JOIN table (for example WHERE ID=...), how can you execute it without a long time?

Comment: @Matthieu . . . A `where` condition should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it this way

```
SELECT SUM(montantCommande) as total 
FROM export_commandes 
INNER JOIN export_adherent AS table_adherent on export_commandes.client_id=table_adherent.ID
```